# checkbox values in an array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have a list of checkboxes for CITY (class='city') .
Now I am creating an array which store all the city checked values.
my code is:

```
$('.city:checked').each(function() {
    city.push(this.value);
});

alert(city);
```

Result: mumbai,delhi

But I want result like 'mumbai','delhi' in array.
please suggest,

Comment: can you add html also

Comment: Actually it array only. But when you do an alert `toString()` function is called on it which will display it comma separated.

Comment: only check-boxes are there in my HTML.

Comment: I want all values inside ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
var city=[];
$('.city:checked').each(function() {
   city.push("'"+this.value+"'");
});
alert(city);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dHZS9/205/)

Comment: Thanks mohit. It works. Sorry I can not vote up as i have only 14 reputation .minimum 15 requires :(

Answer (score 0):

it shows like that in alert but in actual they are array:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var someGlobalArray = new Array;


someGlobalArray=[];
$('.city:checked').each(function() {
    someGlobalArray.push("'" + $(this).val() + "'");
});
alert(someGlobalArray);    
});
```

Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/PBhHK/412/

Answer (score 0):

once you get the result split the result. check below code sample:

```
var res = city.split(',');
```

Comment: I dont want to split .result should be 'mumbai','delhi' not mumbai,delhi